# Scene randomizer issue

Tags: c#, list, random, nullreferenceexception

I’m developing a casual 2D Game on unity. And I’m a little stuck. I have 2 scripts: one loads when the game starts - **(MainMenuScript.cs)**, one loads when every scene starts - **(LevelControlScript.cs)**

I need to randomize scenes, but **index_scene = UnityEngine.Random.Range(a, b)** not quite what I need in my case. But I still need to show scenes in random sequence. I wrote this code where:

**MainMenuScript.cs:**

1. Creates a list, where we put played scenes. It should be initialized once on loading.

**LevelControlScript.cs:**

1. Chooses the next scene randomly and check it with the values in the list.
2. If the list includes that scene - choose another random scene, if it’s not in the list - it plays and after that the scene should be added to the list of played scenes.
3. When all the scenes were played - the list should be cleared.

So, it should rotate until I manually leave the level.

However, I don’t understand why unity shows this error and how to fix it: **NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object LevelControlScript.LoadNextLevel () (at Assets/Scripts/LevelControlScript.cs:606)**

**MainMenuScript:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class MainMenuScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public List<int> remember = new List<int>(); //here

    public void StartLvl()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Scenes/LVL");
    }

    public void Quit()
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

**LevelControlScript:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LevelControlScript : MonoBehaviour {

    MainMenuScript mainmenu; //here

    // Variable to contain current scene build index
    int currentSceneIndex;
    void Start() {

        mainmenu = GetComponent<MainMenuScript>(); //here
        
        // Getting current scene build index
        currentSceneIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;    
    }

    // Method is invoked when correct answer is given
    public void RightAnswer()
    {
        Code...    
    }

    // Method loads next level
    public void LoadNextLevel()
    {
        int index_scene = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 10);
        foreach (int index in mainmenu.remember)
        {
            if (index == index_scene)
            {
                index_scene = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 10);
            }
        }
        if (mainmenu.remember.Count == 10)
        {
            mainmenu.remember.Clear();
        }
        mainmenu.remember.Add(index_scene);
        SceneManager.LoadScene(index_scene);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line exactly is throwing that error? Unity is saying "LevelControlScript.cs:606" i.e line 606, which one is that? Please [edit] your question to highlight the line in question with a either a comment, or a separate code block containing only that line or both

Comment: Also [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @MindSwipe  line 606: foreach (int index in mainmenu.remember)

Comment: So `mainmenu` is null, have you made sure to add the `mainmenu` component to your GameObject that contains the `LevelControlScript`?

Comment: @MindSwipe I'm sorry, but I'm pretty new with it...
I can't use it like GameObject in Unity.
If I add mainmenu to GameObject in my LevelControlScript, like: **public GameObject mainmenu;**
I have an error: error CS0102: The type 'LevelControlScript' already contains a definition for 'mainmenu'.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure if this could help, but since MainMenuScript loads in the in the initial (Menu) scene and is still required in all other scenes) you should probably add [DontDestroyOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) in a start function in the MainMenuScript.

Edit:

Try this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class MainMenuScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public List<int> remember = new List<int>(); //here
    private static bool created = false;

    void Start()
    {
        if (!created)
        {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
            created = true;
        }
    }
    public void StartLvl()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Scenes/LVL");
    }

    public void Quit()
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

This should work, but if it doesn't, try changing LevelControlScript to this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LevelControlScript : MonoBehaviour {
    GameObject mainmenugameobject;
    MainMenuScript mainmenu; //here

    // Variable to contain current scene build index
    int currentSceneIndex;
    void Start() {
        mainmenugameobject = GameObject.Find("Changethistothenameofthemenugameobject"):
        mainmenu = mainmenugameobject.GetComponent<MainMenuScript>(); //here
        
        // Getting current scene build index
        currentSceneIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;    
    }

    // Method is invoked when correct answer is given
    public void RightAnswer()
    {
        Code...    
    }

    // Method loads next level
    public void LoadNextLevel()
    {
        int index_scene = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 10);
        foreach (int index in mainmenu.remember)
        {
            if (index == index_scene)
            {
                index_scene = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 10);
            }
        }
        if (mainmenu.remember.Count == 10)
        {
            mainmenu.remember.Clear();
        }
        mainmenu.remember.Add(index_scene);
        SceneManager.LoadScene(index_scene);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hello, I believe that it should works, but I don't know how input it in my program correctly, because earlier I did this, but it didn't work

Comment: Thanks so much! I tried that you wrote and changed it a bit. It works now :)